# Copy formatted text and store as cell value in Excel 2007

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

I have cells formatted to put a string of less than or equal to 11 numbers into the format of #####-####-##.

**How can I take the formatted value and store is as the actual cell value in another cell?**

eg.

Cell A1 has value 12345678, and is formatted to display 00012-3456-78. I want cell B1 to have a cell value of 00012-3456-78.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in `B1`:

```
=TEXT(A1, "00000-0000-00")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked perfectly. All I had to do was then copy from the cell with the substring function and special paste as "values only". Thanks!

Comment: This was useful for importing an excel file into a web app because I needed the formatted value as a text cell because the importer doesn't pick up the Excel formatting on a cell. This is exactly what I needed--thanks.